# Latency issue with Primefaces overlayPanel - loads to lazy

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am using Primefaces 3.2 with jsf 2 and glassfish 3.1.2.

I have a p:dataTable of users containing avatars of the user. Whenever the user moves the mouse over the avatar a p:overlayPanel appears with more information (lazy loaded) on the user, and disappears when the user moves the cursor away - like this:

`<p:overlayPanel for="avatar" dynamic="true" showEvent="mouseover" hideEvent="mouseout" ...>`

This works very well - as long as the user is "slowhanded". Whenever an user moves the cursor fast above many avatars many of the overlayPanels stay visible. 
For example when the user has the cursor over the position where user avatars are displayed and uses the scroll wheel of his mouse to scroll the usertable down or up.

I believe that the overlaypanel starts to load the information dynamically (`dynamic="true"`) from the server when `showEvent="mouseover"` is dispatched and displays the overlaypanel after the response from the server arrives. 
This way it is not possible to detect whether the cursor is already away when the overlaypanel becomes visible - so the `hideEvent="mouseout"` is never dispatched.

Is there a way to make the primefaces overlaypanel appear directly on mousover, showing a loading gif and update the content into the overlaypanel when the response comes from the server.

Is this a good appraoch or does anyone know any other way to solve this nasty problem?

Thanks Pete

Comment: You lucky one actually get content. While im experiencing exactly the same issue my content is also completely missing. Even a simple h:outputText with no references to the actual row model (that one you speicify with var) isnt displaying. Its sad to see that the devs from primefaces havent even considered a very common enterprise problem (IMO it doesnt look that p:overlayPanel or p:tooltip have been designed to be used in tables).

Comment: Did you test the workflow with firebug? Check for JS errors, also check the content of the ajax response from the server.

Comment: Yes, an ajax request is send. Its really strange; although im not using 3.3 but the latest 3.4 snapshot. It might be a new bug.

Comment: When placing the exactly same markup outside of a table, everything works as expected. I probably will use expandable rows for now. I hope that these bugs will be fixed with the release of 3.4.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As my first answer is already very long and contains valid information, I decided to open a new answer presenting my final approach.

Im now using Primefaces inheritance pattern making the code alot cleaner. Also I noticed that replacing/overwriting the whole `bindEvents` function isnt necessary, as we can remove the old event handlers. Finally this code fixs the latest issue experienced: A hide event before ajax arrival.

```
PrimeFaces.widget.OverlayPanel = PrimeFaces.widget.OverlayPanel
        .extend({

            bindEvents : function() {
                this._super();

                var showEvent = this.cfg.showEvent + '.ui-overlay', hideEvent = this.cfg.hideEvent
                        + '.ui-overlay';

                $(document).off(showEvent + ' ' + hideEvent, this.targetId).on(
                        showEvent, this.targetId, this, function(e) {
                            var _self = e.data;

                            clearTimeout(_self.timer);
                            _self.timer = setTimeout(function() {
                                _self.hidden = false;
                                _self.show();
                            }, 300);
                        }).on(hideEvent, this.targetId, this, function(e) {
                    var _self = e.data;

                    clearTimeout(_self.timer);
                    _self.hidden = true;
                    _self.hide();

                });
            },

            _show : function() {
                if (!this.cfg.dynamic || !this.hidden) {
                    this._super();
                }
            }

        });
```

Im sorry for the poor formatting: Eclipses fault ;)

Answer (score 2):

Wow, finally after a long debuging session and testing various approaches i recognized that the problem isnt the ajax request but the event handlers itself:

```
.on(hideEvent, this.targetId, this, function(e) {
            var _self = e.data;

            if(_self.isVisible()) {
                _self.hide();
            }
        });
```

As you can see, the widget is just hidden if its visible before. If your moving your mouse out too fast, now two things can happen:

- The widget isnt visible at all
- The animation is still going on

In this case the event is discarded and the panel stays visible. As animations are queued, one simply has to remove the if statement to fix the issue. I did this by replacing the whole `bindEvents` method:

```
PrimeFaces.widget.OverlayPanel.prototype.bindEvents =  function() {
    //mark target and descandants of target as a trigger for a primefaces overlay
    this.target.data('primefaces-overlay-target', this.id).find('*').data('primefaces-overlay-target', this.id);

    //show and hide events for target
    if(this.cfg.showEvent == this.cfg.hideEvent) {
        var event = this.cfg.showEvent;

        $(document).off(event, this.targetId).on(event, this.targetId, this, function(e) {
            e.data.toggle();
        });
    }
    else {
        var showEvent = this.cfg.showEvent + '.ui-overlay',
        hideEvent = this.cfg.hideEvent + '.ui-overlay';

        $(document).off(showEvent + ' ' + hideEvent, this.targetId).on(showEvent, this.targetId, this, function(e) {
            var _self = e.data;

            if(!_self.isVisible()) {
                _self.show();
            }
        })
        .on(hideEvent, this.targetId, this, function(e) {
            var _self = e.data;

            _self.hide();

        });
    }

    //enter key support for mousedown event
    this.bindKeyEvents();

    var _self = this;

    //hide overlay when mousedown is at outside of overlay
    $(document.body).bind('mousedown.ui-overlay', function (e) {
        if(_self.jq.hasClass('ui-overlay-hidden')) {
            return;
        }

        //do nothing on target mousedown
        var target = $(e.target);
        if(_self.target.is(target)||_self.target.has(target).length > 0) {
            return;
        }

        //hide overlay if mousedown is on outside
        var offset = _self.jq.offset();
        if(e.pageX < offset.left ||
            e.pageX > offset.left + _self.jq.outerWidth() ||
            e.pageY < offset.top ||
            e.pageY > offset.top + _self.jq.outerHeight()) {

            _self.hide();
        }
    });

    //Hide overlay on resize
    var resizeNS = 'resize.' + this.id;
    $(window).unbind(resizeNS).bind(resizeNS, function() {
        if(_self.jq.hasClass('ui-overlay-visible')) {
            _self.hide();
        }
    });
};
```

Execute this code on load and the issue should be gone.

---

---

As your replacing the js code nevertheless, you can use this oppurtunity to implement quite a nice feature. By using timeouts in the event handlers one can easily implement a little delay not just improving usability (no more thousands of popups appear) but also reducing network traffic:

```
        $(document).off(showEvent + ' ' + hideEvent, this.targetId).on(showEvent, this.targetId, this, function(e) {
            var _self = e.data;

            _self.timer = setTimeout( function(){
                if(!_self.isVisible()) {
                    _self.show();
                }
            }, 300);
        })
        .on(hideEvent, this.targetId, this, function(e) {
            var _self = e.data;

            clearTimeout(_self.timer);
            _self.hide();

        });
```

Ofcourse you can use a global variable to control the delay time. If you want a more flexible approach youll have to overwrite the `encodeScript` method in the `OverlayPanelRender` to transmit an additional property. You could access it then with `_self.cfg.delay`. Notice though that youll have to replace the component model `OverlayPanel` too providing it with an extra attribute.

Comment: Sounds good and bad at the same time, thanks for your effort. I will check this out and return later.

Comment: Did you use Primefaces 3.3 or the Snapshot for 3.4? I am currently looking to adapt your ideas/changes into Primefaces 3.2

Comment: Im using the snapshot for 3.4. I think its from 10.8; im not quite sure on it though. Some bugs i experienced with 3.3 were fixed through updating. Most notable is probably f:param support in p:menuitem.

Comment: As it seems the implementation for 3.2 is slightly different. You can take a look at it at http://primefaces.googlecode.com/svn/primefaces/tags/3_2_RC1/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/overlaypanel/overlaypanel.js . But basically youll have to do the same.

Comment: I already downloaded the complete sources, for now I am adapting the functionality of _self.isVisible() then I will know more. Thanks

Comment: Unfortunatly this does not solve my problem. I debugged all calls to methods.
1) If I remove the 'if' I can see a call to _self:hide() shortly before the loadContent.completehandler calls _self._show() - which displays the overlay again
2) If I don't remove the 'if' I can see the hide() method is never called - I still believe this is the problem.

Comment: Very odd, as im not getting these problems. I gueess youll have to keep track whether the component has been hiden and dont show it if that condition is met. Simply reset this property in the `showEvent` handler before the call to `self._show()`. Instead of completely replacing the `_show` and `hide` methods you could store them somewhere and call them in overriden `_show` , `hide` methods. This way you dont have to replace the whole code.

Answer (score 2):

At the same time I thank you for this brilliant solution I take the opportunity to update it for Primefaces 5.2. In our application the code broke after that upgrade.

Follows the updated code for **Primefaces 5.2**:

```
    PrimeFaces.widget.OverlayPanel.prototype.bindTargetEvents =  function() {
    var $this = this;
    //mark target and descandants of target as a trigger for a primefaces overlay
    this.target.data('primefaces-overlay-target', this.id).find('*').data('primefaces-overlay-target', this.id);

    //show and hide events for target
    if(this.cfg.showEvent === this.cfg.hideEvent) {
        var event = this.cfg.showEvent;

        this.target.on(event, function(e) {
            $this.toggle();
        });
    }
    else {
        var showEvent = this.cfg.showEvent + '.ui-overlaypanel',
        hideEvent = this.cfg.hideEvent + '.ui-overlaypanel';

        this.target
            .off(showEvent + ' ' + hideEvent)
            .on(showEvent, function(e) {
                clearTimeout($this.timer);

                $this.timer = setTimeout(function() {
                    $('.ui-overlaypanel').hide(); 
                    $this.hidden = false;
                    $this.show();
                }, 500);
            })
            .on(hideEvent, function(e) {

                clearTimeout($this.timer); 

                $this.timer = setTimeout(function() {
                    // don't hide if hovering overlay
                    if(! $this.jq.is(":hover")) {
                        $this.hide();
                    }
                }, 100);
            });
    }

    $this.target.off('keydown.ui-overlaypanel keyup.ui-overlaypanel').on('keydown.ui-overlaypanel', function(e) {
        var keyCode = $.ui.keyCode, key = e.which;

        if(key === keyCode.ENTER||key === keyCode.NUMPAD_ENTER) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    })
    .on('keyup.ui-overlaypanel', function(e) {
        var keyCode = $.ui.keyCode, key = e.which;

        if(key === keyCode.ENTER||key === keyCode.NUMPAD_ENTER) {
            $this.toggle();
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
};
```

I also added an extra feature which allows the user to move the mouse over the overlay without hiding it. It should hide when you move the mouse out of it then which I accomplished through:

```
<p:overlayPanel .... onShow="onShowOverlayPanel(this)" ...>

function onShowOverlayPanel(ovr) {
    ovr.jq.on("mouseleave", function(e) {
        ovr.jq.hide();
    });
}
```

Hope you enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

It's been a long time, but in case anyone bumps into this problem, a `showDelay` attribute was added to the `overlayPanel` to solve this problem [starting from Primefaces 6.2](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/1947). However, it is not in the official documentation for some reason.