# Primefaces p:overlayPanel like facebook

Tags: primefaces, overlay

I need a overlayPanel like facebook.
1) Friend -> hover over friend -> a panel appear with some options (add friend, mutable friends....)
2) I can hover over this panel and click the buttons
3) if I hover out, the panel disapear.

How can I do this?
I think I need the right showEvent and hideEvent. But what are the correct?
Thank you so much for our help

Comment: p:overlayPanel is the right component for this. There is an example in the showcase: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/overlay/overlayPanel.xhtml - just replace the dataTable from the example with the components and events you need.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I know this component. The question is for me: what are the right events?
I try something but I can't find the right solution.

Could you help me, please.

Answer (score 1):

I would say `showEvent="mouseover"` and `hideEvent="mouseout"` is what you are looking for.

Comment: hideEvent="mouseout" is not exactly this, what I want. Which other hideEvents are there?

Comment: I don't know exactly what you are looking for. I thought you want the overlay panel to disapear when moving mouse away from element. So can you specify a little bit? [Here](http://javascript.info/tutorial/mouse-events) you can find a nice overview about mouse events. Maybe there you can find what you are looking for.

Comment: I´m looking for the same as in facebook:Hover a name of a friend (is a link) -> a new overlayPanel appear -> I can hover over this overlayPanel and click some buttons (e.g. "add friend") -> if I go with the mouse out of the panel -> the outputPanl disapear.

Comment: any ideas for this issue?

Comment: any help? More than 6 month ago :(

Answer (score 1):

Just found the solution in this question:
[Latency issue with Primefaces overlayPanel - loads to lazy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11900998/latency-issue-with-primefaces-overlaypanel-loads-to-lazy)

This did the trick:

```
<p:overlayPanel .... onShow="onShowOverlayPanel(this)" ...>

function onShowOverlayPanel(ovr) {
    ovr.jq.on("mouseleave", function(e) {
        ovr.jq.hide();
    });
}
```